# Outdated link on Privileges page

Tags: bug, status-completed, privileges-page

On the Privileges page [Create tag synonyms](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms), there is a link that isn't longer valid:

> The goal is to save manual retagging work by making the retagging automatic for common tag mistakes.

*manual retagging work* is linkified and that link leads to `/help/privileges/retag-questions`, but that privilege doesn't longer exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for suggesting this fix! I have addressed this in a similar post on the Stack Overflow Meta site: [Privilege synonym page has a dead link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258653/privilege-synonym-page-has-a-dead-link)